# Is it possible to output LaTeX in a shell prompt?

Tags: shell, prompt, latex

There are several "lambda" prompts (i.e., shell prompts which use the $\lambda$ symbol). While these look nice in theory, many fonts do not use the lambda symbol that I like: $\lambdaup$. I'm not sure if it's possible to embed compiled LaTeX in a shell prompt, e.g., fish, zsh... but if it is, can anyone tell me how?

Turns out the Unix stack exchange does not render LaTeX, but a simple Google search will show what I mean.

Comment: not sure I get what you want, I simply go to wikipedia for lambda, copy , λ from that page and set `PS1="foo λ  > "`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have a few options:

1. Find a monospace font with a lambda you like; the Nerd fonts have a lambda that looks like this, for example:

   [image: nerd font lambda]

   Not sure if you like that.
2. *Make* a monospace font with a lambda you like, by, e.g., using something like FontForge to steal the glyph from one font and import it into another.
3. Use a terminal that supports images, like [kitty](https://sw.kovidgoyal.net/kitty/). Use LaTeX or whatever other method you like to produce an image. (You can easily convert LaTeX to images with a tool like `pdftoppm -png`.) And then define a PROMPT_COMMAND function that displays that image.

   I would put more effort into this if I actually wanted it for myself; get the sizing just right, make the background transparent, etc., but just to give you the rough idea:

   ```
   # .bashrc
    lambdaprompt() {
        # skip a line so the images aren't on top of each other
        echo
        # display the lambda using kitty's icat kitten
        kitty +kitten icat --align left /path/to/lambda.png;
        # move cursor back up
        echo -e '\033[3A'
        # have the prompt start after the image
        PS1='   '
    }
    PROMPT_COMMAND=lambdaprompt
   ```

   [image: lambda prompt]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

No. The shell operates on characters and latex does not output as characters, at least not without stripping the important TeX formatting away.